# Determine if argument is a class (A+ promise implementation) or a callable function

Tags: javascript, promise

I have a function which expects a single argument of either a function or a class and I have to do different action for each of the two.

Example pseudocode:

```
function myFunction(callback) {
    if ( /* callback is a Promise class */ ) {
        return new callback(function (resolve, reject) {
            // logic
            resolve();
        });
    } else if ( /* callback is a callable function */ ) {
        // logic
        callback(); // Realistically this would not be called at the end of logic block.
    } else {
        // throw error
    }
}
```

I'd like to offer support for arbitrary Promise library implementing the A+ standard, so the developer can pass whatever implementation they're already using and do not have to perform any workarounds or use my implementation. Keep in mind that I'm not talking just about the native implementations in modern VMs, but am also targeting [other implementations](https://github.com/promises-aplus/promises-spec/blob/master/implementations.md).  The callable function option is there as a fallback if developer doesn't (want to) use Promise library. I hope this explanation makes some sense.

From what I've tried I always get same result for both the class and callable function since classes in JavaScript are just functions. The only workaround I was able to do is check `callback.length`, but this functionality is very fragile and will most likely break in any real use case.

Comment: There's really no such thing as a "class" in JavaScript. What do you mean by "class" here?

Comment: @Pointy please read the full question. Basically what I want to know is if I can instantiate the argument or call it.

Comment: Please just make a better interface that doesn't have to solve this confusing problem.  Like pass another argument that indicates how the callback argument is to be treated.  Or pass an object with properties that indicate which it is.  Basically you have designed a confusing interface and that's why you have this problem.

Comment: @jfriend00 You are right that it's quite confusing. Now when I think of it, I'm trying to create something similar to how `jQuery.ajax` works, if you ignore the "callback can be Promise" part. I am thinking about adding A+ promises polyfill and using callback as optional argument.

Comment: jQuery has their own promise implementation so I'm not sure how that fits with your attempt to optionally use a passed-in promise implementation.  Doesn't seem like the same problem. Might be better to just have a config option for your library that specifies a promise constructor to use if the developer wants to use something other than the globally defined `Promise` constructor.

Comment: I know it has. I said if you ignore that part, I used jQuery as an example of what I wanted to achieve.

Comment: jQuery ajax returns a promise and you can either use that promise or you can pass in a success/fail callback as one of the arguments or options.  The developer can then use either one.  The code in your question doesn't look anything like that.

Comment: If you were to read everything I've said you would know that I am thinking it's not the best approach and do it like jQuery does it (*I am thinking about adding A+ promises polyfill and using callback as optional argument.*), same as you've just described.

Comment: But your question specifically asked how to do it the way you are.  It didn't ask for a different/better way to do it (or at least I don't see that part of your question).  Further, you selected a best answer that just furthers your current direction.  Is there still an open part of this question?  Or do you have everything you want already?  I can't tell.

Comment: I have accepted it because it answers my question and I have upvoted it because it's recommending a better way to do it. Thanks to your comments I have realized that my idea is bad and that there are better solutions. Therefore I have commented about what I was really going for and a better solution I have found.

Comment: OK, I was confused about what you were asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not really any difference between arbitrary callback functions and constructor functions.

ES6 will add some distinctions here (e.g. not giving arrow functions a `.prototype` property), but none of those will be reliable either.

The only real distinction between constructors and "normal" functions is their prototype. If you specifically target Promise implementations, all of the serious libraries will have a `.then()` method there.

So you can use

```
if (typeof callback == "function")
    if (callback.prototype && typeof callback.prototype.then == "function")
        // looks like a Promise constructor
    else
        // an ordinary function
```

Of course, this doesn't work for 100% of imaginable cases. There might be other classes with `then` methods, and there are Promises/A+ conformant implementations that make `.then()` an instance instead of a prototype method. Also don't forget that the `Promise` constructor is not yet standardised (it is in ES6, but not in Promises/A+).

---

A better idea than using the `Promise` constructor pattern would be `Promise.resolve`. You'd just construct an arbitrary thenable which then does get assimilated by every promise implementation. You wouldn't even need to be given that resolver as an argument, you should just return the thenable in absence of a callback function argument. Your consumers can then just wrap all calls to you API in a `Promise.resolve(…)` of their favourite libary.

That's how Promise interoperability was designed in the first place, so it will absolutely work.

Comment: Thanks for this, I have not thought about the `.then`. I agree about better solution but I do not fully understand what do you mean, can you please provide an example?

Comment: Just use your own `Promise` constructor. If you want to use promises internally, choose your favourite libary, if not then just use something the builds thenables (which don't need to adhere to any spec). Then if no callback is passed, return such a thenable. Your consumers will cast them to promises of their own favourite library themselves, without passing you anything.

Comment: The promise constructor is standardized in the promise constructor spec the same way `then` is standardized in Promises/A+.

Comment: If we assume sane code (bluebird promisifyAll does :D), then constructor functions always have at least 1 property in its `.prototype` while a normal function never has anything on `.prototype` (.constructor is exception and doesn't count)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: The [constructor spec](https://github.com/promises-aplus/constructor-spec) is still not approved by A+, even if it became the de facto standard and is used in ES6.